# Editable textareas in header and footer need to show changes in both places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a header and a footer of an html invoice containing contact information. Whatever content changes I make in the header I want to show them in the footer and vice versa.

For example if I change the phone number in the header, it should change in the footer once I click out of the text box. I've only managed it to work in one and on enter unfortunately:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getValue() {
        var x;
        x = document.getElementById("phone-number").value;
        document.getElementById("phone-number-footer").value = x;
    }
    $('#phone-number').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) { //Enter key pressed
            getTextBoxValue();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When asking a question about JavaScript that depends on HTML interaction (in this case with the `<textarea>` elements, in the header and footer) please post enough of your "*[mcve]*" code that we can reproduce your problem, ideally using HTML that closely (or precisely) matches your own situation. While the currently-posted answer works I don't believe it's the most efficient solution, but an efficient solution would depend - I think - on your HTML, which you haven't shown. Consider taking a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines as well, to see how to write a question that invites good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript function does not work inside document.ready function. It should moved below or above document.ready function.

So please check below solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('blur', '#phone-number', function(e) {
        getHeaderTextBoxValue();
    });
    $(document).on('keypress', '#phone-number', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            getHeaderTextBoxValue();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('blur', '#phone-number-footer', function(e) {
        getFooterTextBoxValue();
    });
    $(document).on('keypress', '#phone-number-footer', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            getFooterTextBoxValue();
        }
    });
});
function getHeaderTextBoxValue() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("phone-number").value;
    document.getElementById("phone-number-footer").value = x;
}
function getFooterTextBoxValue() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("phone-number-footer").value;
    document.getElementById("phone-number").value = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting an error when I use the above code. I am running my project on Codekit and got the following:

 $(document)on('blur', '#email-address', function(e) {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (on)

Comment: ohh... my mistake. I just forget to add . before add. Can you please check now? I just have edited my answer.

Comment: Still no success :(

I've created a codepen and tried working on it off there with no success. When I change values in both text areas, the changes do not match.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXzLjm

Comment: It's because you need to add jquery.js file in external files. Check here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRmjeY

Comment: Ah such an obvious mistake, my bad! Thank you I see it is working now :) However how do I make it so that the changes I make in the footer text area also change the content in the header? Currently it is only one way

Comment: I am updating my answer. Check answer here as well https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRmjeY

Comment: This is perfect! Works just how I wanted it. Thank you, Pratik :)